# Netbeans import java.util.Scanner illegal start of type

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I seem to be getting this error when I'm trying to import the scanner package and I can't figure out why.

**Here is my script.**

```
package week.pkg1;

public class Week1 {

  import java.util.Scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String setName = null;
        Integer setAge = null;
        Double SetWeight = null;
        Double setHeight = null;

        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("*   Welcome to GymsRUs Health Application   *");
        System.out.println("*                   Version 1.0             *");
        System.out.println("*                      CIS355A              *");
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Please Input Name: ");

        setName = 
    }

}
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

*Code added in frame.

Comment: `setName =` is not a valid statement, you are missing some code. Should be something like `setName = "something";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports must happen **before** any class declarations!

Simply move any import directly after the package declaration; and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove import line and then just click CTRL+SHIFT+I. It will add a class from a specific package into a proper place of code.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Import statement should be below to package and above class declaration.

ex-

```
package week.pkg1;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Week1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

2- The `setName =` is also not a valid statement.